# How to make admin that can't delete products in Magento?

Tags: magento, roles

As title says I wan't to make admin that can't delete product but he can add or update products.

Answer (score 0):

Create a custom module that overwrite Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Product_Edit and with a  ACL. Then create a custom role and assign these users to it

See /app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Catalog/Product/Edit.php

```
protected function _prepareLayout()
{
  .....
  if ($this->getProduct()->isDeleteable() && <acl>) {
      $this->setChild('delete_button',
      $this->getLayout()->createBlock('adminhtml/widget_button')
            ->setData(array(
                'label'     => Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Delete'),
                'onclick'   => 'confirmSetLocation(\''.Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Are you sure?').'\', \''.$this->getDeleteUrl().'\')',
                'class'  => 'delete'
            ))
    );
}
```

Take a look @  http://www.atwix.com/magento/view-product-button/